# QT Future Watcher With mail Client

Tags: c++, qt, email

Hi I am using the code from here https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5/tree/master/smtp_attachements to send mail from my qt application and it's work fine, but when I use future wacht to run the mail sender in another thread it does'nt work

```
QFuture<void> f4 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::sendMail); // this doesnot work
//sendMail(); //this work
```

Here is the mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QSettings"
#include "QFuture"
#include "QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->sendBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(test()));
    connect(ui->exitBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->browseBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(browse()));
}

void MainWindow::browse()
{
    files.clear();

    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setDirectory(QDir::homePath());
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);

    if (dialog.exec())
        files = dialog.selectedFiles();

    QString fileListString;
    foreach(QString file, files)
        fileListString.append( "\"" + QFileInfo(file).fileName() + "\" " );

    ui->file->setText( fileListString );

}
void MainWindow::test(){

    QFuture<void> f4 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::sendMail);
    //sendMail();
}



void MainWindow::sendMail()
{
    Smtp* smtp = new Smtp(ui->uname->text(), ui->paswd->text(), ui->server->text(), ui->port->text().toInt());
    connect(smtp, SIGNAL(status(QString)), this, SLOT(mailSent(QString)));

    if( !files.isEmpty() )
        smtp->sendMail(ui->uname->text(), ui->rcpt->text() , ui->subject->text(),ui->msg->toPlainText(), files );
    else
        smtp->sendMail(ui->uname->text(), ui->rcpt->text() , ui->subject->text(),ui->msg->toPlainText());
}

void MainWindow::mailSent(QString status)
{
    if(status == "Message sent")
        QMessageBox::warning( 0, tr( "Qt Simple SMTP client" ), tr( "Message sent!\n\n" ) );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "smtp.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void sendMail();
    void mailSent(QString);
    void browse();
    void test();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStringList files;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The smtp class is as shown here, I haven't touch anything

https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5/blob/master/smtp_attachements/smtp.h
https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5/blob/master/smtp_attachements/smtp.cpp

Any one know why it's not working when running in a thread using future watcher.

Thanks
Haris

Comment: a) I don't see any `QFutureWatcher` being used; b) what does "it doesn't work" mean exactly?; c) you have a memory leak as you don't delete `Smtp* smtp`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, you can see a function test() from where I need to execute it as a thread. It doesn't work means the mail not sending and the slot mailSent() not getting called. I will fix the memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `QtConcurrent::run` just runs a single function, in your case `sendMail`, in a separate thread. As soon as this function returns, the thread **is not active** anymore and the slots in `Smtp` will not be called.

Either change your function `sendMail` to **not** return until the mail is sent or use a [`QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) and move `Smtp* stmp` to it using `QObject::moveToThread`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay, can I do this with Qt future watcher implementation by monitoring cuncurrent::run().

Comment: No, you have to change the logic in class `Smtp` from non-blocking to blocking. Otherwise, `sendMail` returns too early.

Comment: I think the method sendMail to not return until the mail is sent  can implement fast , but no idea how to block this function.

Comment: Or loop inside a while loop till the slot get called in `sendMail` function?

Comment: why don't you just move `Smtp` to a separate `QThread` as I wrote above?

Comment: Actually I am not well familiar with the thread, and I have to integrate this to my application as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @m.s. I have moved the `Smtp* smtp`  as my class variable and tried the same way but still the result same.

Comment: @Haris your original question ("Any one know why it's not working") is solved. please ask a new question on how to change your current code.

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks for giving me the hint, but the same reason for not working while moving the  `Smtp* smtp` as my class variable.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "moving ... as my class variable". Ask a new question containing your current code and we'll see.

Comment: Ok I will ask new question.

Comment: Hi @m.s. I am accepting your answer, and asked a  new question.