# QT Cuncurrent With mail Client

Tags: c++, qt, email

Hi I already asked my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087596/qt-future-watcher-with-mail-client) and understand why it's not working, now I have modified source code by moving the Smptp object as class variable , but still not working.

What I need to implement is send mail from a thread I chose `QtConcurrent::run()` for doing this but the slot not getting called after sending button clicked.

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QSettings"
#include "QFuture"
#include "QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->sendBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(test()));
    connect(ui->exitBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->browseBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(browse()));
}

void MainWindow::browse()
{
    files.clear();

    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setDirectory(QDir::homePath());
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);

    if (dialog.exec())
        files = dialog.selectedFiles();

    QString fileListString;
    foreach(QString file, files)
        fileListString.append( "\"" + QFileInfo(file).fileName() + "\" " );

    ui->file->setText( fileListString );

}
void MainWindow::test(){


    QFuture<void> f4 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::sendMail); // this not work
    //sendMail(); // this works
}






void MainWindow::sendMail()
{
    smtp = new Smtp(ui->uname->text(), ui->paswd->text(), ui->server->text(), ui->port->text().toInt());
    connect(smtp, SIGNAL(status(QString)), this, SLOT(mailSent(QString)));

    if( !files.isEmpty() )
        smtp->sendMail(ui->uname->text(), ui->rcpt->text() , ui->subject->text(),ui->msg->toPlainText(), files );
    else
        smtp->sendMail(ui->uname->text(), ui->rcpt->text() , ui->subject->text(),ui->msg->toPlainText());


}

void MainWindow::mailSent(QString status)
{
    if(status == "Message sent")
        QMessageBox::warning( 0, tr( "Qt Simple SMTP client" ), tr( "Message sent!\n\n" ) );

    delete smtp;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "smtp.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void sendMail();
    void mailSent(QString);
    void browse();
    void test();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStringList files;
    Smtp* smtp ;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

If I call `sendMail();` directly it works, but using `QFuture<void> f4 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::sendMail);` it's not working, not working means the slot not get called, how can I resolve this issue?

I am referring the code from here https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5/tree/master/smtp_attachements

Thanks
Haris

Comment: why would having `smtp` as a member variable solve the problem I described in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31089465/678093)?

Comment: No this is not done by your answer I have just tried myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution as I already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31089465/678093) is to use a `QThread` instead of `QtConcurrent::run`.
There is a detailed example contained in the Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

The following code adapts this example to your use case.
`smtp` is moved to the `workerThread`. The communication between the main thread and the `workerThread` is done using signals and slots.
Be aware that you are not allowed to call **any** GUI related functions (such as showing message boxes etc.) in `Smtp` anymore!
This has to be done in the main thread.

User name, password etc. should probably also be passed through the signal to `Smtp::sendMail`.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QThread>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class Smtp;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void sendMailButtonClicked();
    void mailSent(QString);
    void browse();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStringList files;
    Smtp* smtp;
    QThread workerThread;
signals:
    void sendMail(const QString &from, const QString &to, const QString &subject, const QString &body, QStringList files);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "smtp.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->sendBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(sendMailButtonClicked()));
    connect(ui->exitBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->browseBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(browse()));
    smtp = new Smtp(ui->uname->text(), ui->paswd->text(), ui->server->text(), ui->port->text().toInt());
    smtp->moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendMail(QString,QString,QString,QString,QStringList)), smtp, SLOT(sendMail(QString,QString,QString,QString,QStringList)));
    connect(smtp, SIGNAL(status(QString)), this, SLOT(mailSent(QString)));
    workerThread.start();
}

void MainWindow::browse()
{
    files.clear();

    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setDirectory(QDir::homePath());
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);

    if (dialog.exec())
        files = dialog.selectedFiles();

    QString fileListString;
    foreach(QString file, files)
        fileListString.append( "\"" + QFileInfo(file).fileName() + "\" " );

    ui->file->setText( fileListString );

}

void MainWindow::mailSent(QString status)
{
    if(status == "Message sent")
        QMessageBox::warning( 0, tr( "Qt Simple SMTP client" ), tr( "Message sent!\n\n" ) );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::sendMailButtonClicked()
{
    emit sendMail(ui->uname->text(), ui->rcpt->text() , ui->subject->text(),ui->msg->toPlainText(), files );
}
```

in **smtp.h**: set `sendMail` to be a slot:

```
public slots:
    void sendMail( const QString &from, const QString &to,
                   const QString &subject, const QString &body,
                   QStringList files = QStringList());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort for you put to helping me, do I need to change anything in the Smtp header or source because I am getting an error `QObject::connect: No such slot Smtp::sendMail(QString,QString,QString,QString,QStringList)`

Comment: @Haris yes, `sendMail` must be a slot. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks one more, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Hi, One more doubt, have you tested the code, beacuse I am getting the abort before the message get send with an error `ASSERT failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread."`

Comment: I already covered that in my answer: "Be aware that you are not allowed to call any GUI related functions (such as showing message boxes etc.) in Smtp anymore! This has to be done in the main thread."

Comment: Hi, I would like to know, have you tested the code there, because the first time the the mail sending works but from the next time when I click send button the click event triggered, but the signal `sendMail` not getting emitted any idea? . My ultimate intention is integrate this code with my application for sending mail continuously from background when an event occurred.

Comment: @Haris how do you know the signal is not emitted? I did not extensively test it, but it is standard Qt code (as shown in the documentation).

Comment: I have tested it with debugger, the second time the debugger not reaching to the break point which I put on the corresponding slot

Comment: @Haris Then probably `smtp` was deleted. You explicitly call `deleteLater` if `state==Close`. Don't delete `smtp` as you want to reuse it.